# How can I change the color of a link?

Tags: css

I have this:

```
<div id="color">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to user.name, edit_user_path(user) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And in application.css:

```
#color {
  color:blue
}
```

In my layout file I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

But the text of my links is black instead of blue. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#color a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this.

in **application.css**

```
.color {
  color: blue;
}
```

And In your **view**

```
 <%= link_to user.name, edit_user_path(user), class: "color" %>
```